# Persuading users to mark questions as "Answered"

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, users, unanswered-questions

I'm seeing a lot of old posts being automatically recirculated by the database.

The only reason it does this is that, as far as the database knows, they haven't been successfully answered.

Is there a mailshot facility we can use to remind users to accept answers that satisfy their questions?

If we can get users into the habit of marking answers rather than just upvoting them then some of these older posts will stop recirculating.

Answer (score 3):

If memory serves, upvoting answers also works to remove them from this recirculation, though I forget what the threshold is.  I'm not sure there's a good way to convince askers to mark solutions as that tends to be a problem across many SE sites, but voting up answers is a good way for the community to vote the the question is answered.

Comment: Having a positive score (or an accepted answer) is enough to meet the threshold for being considered "answered", per the MSE post [Why does the "Unanswered Questions" tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870/335251) – and the blog post cited by the answer: [OK, Now Define “Answered”](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/30/ok-now-define-answered/)

Answer (score 2):

We do try to encourage new folks to mark answers as accepted, and for registered users, this typically works... But for unregistered users, the percentage of return visits is rather low.

There isn't any sort of mailshot functionality either, and even if there was, it wouldn't work for unregistered users either.

But as AJ pointed out, upvoting good answers does take questions off the circulation, and will give future readers the community view on "best answer" even if the OP never accepts.